# adding logic to loginController

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, authentication

I want to add logic to create a profile_id cookie when the user logs in of the users first profile id.

```
setcookie("profile_id", Auth::user()->profiles[0]->id,  time() + 86400, "/");
```

I have placed this line in other controllers so I know that part works, but I can't seem to "hack" the loginController as there are no methods (update/create/etc) to slip that logic into.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;


class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;
    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/settings';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');

    }
}
```

I am not sure what is going on with this controller and can't seem to figure out how it works or what it is doing. Any pointers or guidance to understand this code would be appreciated.

- I've opted out of using a cookieController since that line works and is the only cookie I need for this app.
- If context of function helps I have a user with many profiles, the nav-bar has a drop down to choose the active profile. The nav-bar when not "dropped down" shows the current selected user based on the profile_id cookie. When the user first logs in no profile has been selected and no profile_id cookie exists so it breaks upon login. I got around that by redirecting to a page that has no nav-bar and a logic block that says if the cookie doesn't exist create one, but it's not a long term solution.

Answer (score 0):

See https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6.x/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php for all the functions that are contained within the `AuthenticatesUsers` trait.

You can for instance override the `login` function like this:

**LoginController.php**

```php
use AuthenticatesUsers {
    // Rename one function to another name, so we can use the original name ourselves.
    login as loginTrait;
}

public function login(Request $request)
{
    // And here you can put your own logic, a good starting point is
    // the source (the `AuthenticatesUsers::login()` function).

    // Call the original function.
    $this->loginTrait($request);
}
```

Also, there is an `protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)` defined which you can freely override. This gets called after a user is authenticated.

Comment: Sorry I am not following fully. the user logs in, that hits loginController, AuthenticatesUsers is called in with use, name changed, and then your saying I should add this login function, and then continue to $redirectTo = /home or place the redirect inside this login function?

Comment: im giving you pointers on how to modify the LoginController. The `AuthenticatesUsers` trait is basically the full implementation of how Laravel handles logins. Check the source to see what it does. You can track down what method is actually called since you are likely doing some POST request to an endpoint, and it will be defined in your routes (either manually or through `Auth::routes()`).  The `Auth::routes()` helper will add `Auth\LoginController@login` for you.

Answer (score 0):

I would override the `authenticated` method and add your logic there:

```
 /**
     * The user has been authenticated.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  mixed  $user
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {
        redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath())->cookie(
            'profile_id', $user->profiles[0]->id, now()->addSeconds(86400)
        );
    }
```

The reason this works is that once you're authenticated, it hits the `sendLoginResponse` (as defined in the Trait), and calls the `authenticated` function. That function is empty by default, so it returns `null` which triggers the `null coalesce` comparison in the `sendLoginResponse`. what we've done here is copy the fall through logic of that method and added a cookie to be returned with the response.

Comment: interesting, I don't quite understand the code with redirect()-> to cookie, is that happening before $redirectTo or in place of? Why send a cookie to be returned with a response as opposed to creating one with setcookie()?

Answer (score 0):

[`AuthenticatesUsers::sendLoginResponse`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v6.9.0/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php#L103) is returning a [`RedirectResponse`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v6.9.0/src/Illuminate/Http/RedirectResponse.php) after the user is authenticated.

A straight forward way is to override `sendLoginResponse` and include the cookie in the original response headers through [`ResponseTrait::cookie`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v6.9.0/src/Illuminate/Http/ResponseTrait.php#L97).

```php
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;
    #...

    /**
    * Send the response after the user was authenticated.
    *
    * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
    * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
    */
    protected function sendLoginResponse(Request $request)
    {
        return parent::sendLoginResponse($request)
               ->cookie(
                   new Cookie(
                      "profile_id",
                      Auth::user()->profiles[0]->id,
                      time() + 86400,
                      "/"
                  )
              );
    }
}
```

Comment: to clarify, do I leave the rest of my code, and add this protected function? Is this similar to a life-cycle method in react? Something that will get called behind the scenes but I can also call it and add in the logic?

Comment: Yes, leave the rest of the code and add the protected method. Remember to import the `Cookie` class. The method would override that declared in the `AuthenticateUsers` trait. It would be called behind the scenes